# Can ruby scripts be precompiled into a binary?

Tags: ruby, compilation, freebsd

I'm working on a Ruby script that will need to be deployed onto systems without a ruby interpreter.  It will need to run on FreeBSD systems which uses the ELF format.

I know there is a ruby2exe project to compile ruby scripts to run on Windows, but is it easy or even possible to do that on other operating systems?

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty vague. Did you ever solve this, and if so how?

Comment: Sadly I don't think I did. I think I eventually just gave up on it. For anyone coming later on if I were to do it again I would look at using libruby or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked whether Rubinius or JRuby would allow you to precompile your code?

Answer (score 6):

Aside from bytecode that requires a VM to run, Ruby cannot be compiled. It is an interpreted langauge and as such requires an interpreter. ruby2exe packages a ruby interpreter and runtime library with your application.

Comment: So theres no kind of ruby2exe project for other operating systems?